# Can I cut into a header to install a taller exterior door?

Tags: doors, framing, beam

I have a double wide mobile home with existing slider and replacing it with french doors.  The size is going from 71 1/2 x 76 to 71 1/2 x 80. I don't believe that there are cripple studs above the header, just a solid header.

My idea is to cut into the header a bit more than needed for the door to allow me to add a new plate under what is left of the header instead of replacing the header. Is that a sufficient fix? Should I not use wood but use a steel plate under the header?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to picture what you're talking about; would you add a diagram and/or pictures? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Voting to close. We don't have nearly enough information to assess this, and therefore it becomes a matter of opinion (which is specifically off-topic on DIYSE).

Comment: I think there is enough information to say it is a bad idea. How often have you cut +4-1/2 inches into a header of any kind?

Comment: What is the span of the ceiling/roof joists resting on the existing header?

Comment: You could consider just getting a shorter door even if you have to have it ordered. This would save considerable time and also not get into any structural issues. It may cost a bit more but this cost may be negated from all the other work you are going to encounter.

Answer (score 2):

I would not cut into the header, steel plate is very weak with a load on its flat side. I beams get their strength from the width and thickness of the Webb. I could stand on a 6’ long 4” wide 3/8”  steel plate and bend it so no I would not Do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the header if you're going to do this. As Ed Beal said, steel is weaker on its flat side - so is wood for that matter. IIRC a door that wide should have a 12" thick header, although maybe mobile homes have different rules.